# Magento configurable product inventory screwed up after order (qty error)

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

We experience a strange bug with configurable products in Magento 1.7: When a certain size or color of a configurable product is ordered, the inventory quantity of that product version is reduced with the square amount of it.

Example:

- When you order 1 product X in size Y, the inventory qty in the admin is reduced with 1.
- When you order 2 products X in size Y, the inventory qty in the admin is reduced with 4.
- When you order 6 products X in size Y, the inventory qty in the admin is reduced with 36.

This behaviour only happens with config products, luckily not with the simple products. (Even though a config product is a collection of simple products, so it's weird afterall.)

Anyone ever experienced this before or maybe a clue where to start looking?

Comment: **FIXED!** It appeared to be a bug in the magento plugin Shipping Table Rates by Amasty and has been fixed in version 2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

First, look at the `sales_flat_order_item` table to check whether its a frontend bug (where you really are ordering 4 but is displaying 2) or a backend bug (where you really are ordering 2 but 4 is coming off). If it is a backend bug, start looking in `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::subtractQuoteInventory`

Comment: Hmmm table sales_flat_order_item gave some good insight. When I order one config product, it shows 2 records: one for the config product and one for the actual (child) simple product. So far so good. But then yes also here: Qty config = 5 and Qty simple = 25! See screenshot http://i.imgur.com/eZb9t4e.png ... I also checked some docs on Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::subtractQuoteInventory but I couldn't find a link to the issue (yet).

Comment: @Jeff_Cro also look at sales_flat_quote_item while it is in your cart and see the qtys there

Comment: great suggestion! I see that here everything goes well: Qty config = 5 and Qty simple = 5 too. So it must go wrong somewhere in the transition from quote to order ... Any suggestion where to start looking on that?

Comment: Sure. In <code>Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote</code> it calls <code>Mage_Sales_Model_Convert_Quote::itemToOrderItem</code>